# Nginx config for location/api

Tags: authentication, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

Placed frontend and backend in nginx. I'm trying to correctly configure that after authorization, nginx redirected me to the original page.

Nginx Conf:

```
            ##Frontend
            server_name atlas.com;
            location / {
                       root /ops/front_2.0/dist/;
                       index  index.html;
                       }
            ##Backend
            location /api {
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
```

With this configuration, the backend does not work, I will not get to the authorization page and a 404 Not Found error occurs.
But if, with the same settings, you place the Backend on another domain name, for example:

```
            server_name server.atlas.com;
            location / {
                       proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
                       proxy_set_header Host $host;
                       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                      
                     }
```

Then everything works fine. But such a solution does not suit me, since it is not convenient to use for Frontend, since a CORS error is raised.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? both API and website from same nginx config file?